# how to display the sum of values in labels on kendo ui stacked bar mvc (using .net mvc)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I want to know how to display the sum of values in labels on kendo ui stacked bar mvc (using .net mvc).

I know it can be achieved using javascript. The js code is:

```
$(function(){
        //create Kendo UI Chart
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            dataSource:{
                data:[{
                    a: 22,
                    b: 11,
                    c: 33
                },{
                    a: 2,
                    b: 1,
                    c: 3
                }],
                schema: {
                    parse: function(response){
                        return processResponse(response);
                    }
                }
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
                stack: true
            },
            series: [{
                field: "a",
                name: "a"
            },{
                field: "b",
                name: "b"
            },{
                field: "c",
                name: "c",
                labels: {
                    //get total via dataItem
                    template: "#= dataItem.total #",
                    visible: true
                }
            }],
            legend: {
                visible: true,
                position: "bottom"
            }
        })
    })

    function processResponse(response){
        console.log(response);
        var length = response.length,
            item, i; 

        for (i=0; i<length; i++){
            item = response[i];
            //sum of a + b + c
            item.total = item.a + item.b + item.c;
        }
        return response;            
    }
```

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

I want to achieve the same thing using .net mvc . Is there any way of passing schema as in the above code to series.column attribute?. The below is the js fiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rsLt/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If using Kendo MVC, I'd just do the work on the server side by extending my data class:

```
public partial class myDataClass
{
    public int Total
    {
        get
        {
            return this.a + this.b + this.c;
        }
    }
```